# Updating iOS sdk from delphi 11.3 is very slow

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

When from delphi I try to update the iOS SDK it's very slow (it's take days to finish).

- macOS ventura (in vmware) + xcode 14.2
- delphi Alexandria 11.3
- no antivirus installed
- I also try to reinstall macos ventura from scratch (clean install) and xcode 14.2 nothing change
- On other way, deploying or signing app via paserver look ok, it's fast.
- Not necessary connected to 11.3 release

How can I debug this problem?

Comment: Buy a real mac device

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable
net.link.generic.system.hwcksum_rx=0
net.link.generic.system.hwcksum_tx=0
macos ventura
put the commands to file /etc/sysctrl.conf
restart